# Rearrange common functions in specific order with PhpStorm

Tags: php, intellij-idea, plugins, ide, phpstorm

PhpStorm has a nice little rearrange feature, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have a set of functions that my framework uses in every page. I want them to always be in the same order (and hopefully have 2 newlines between each one). For example:

```
class myClass {


    function head() {}


    function css() {}


    function html() {}


    function js() {}


}
```

I set up up my arrange tab under Settings > Editor > Code Style > PHP to look like this:

[image]

After doing this, clicking the Rearrange Code option still did nothing. I've also tried adding method to each one, like this:

[image]

It made no difference.

Is there a way to get PhpStorm to automatically rearrange functions in a user defined order (hopefully with 2 newlines in between each)?

Comment: Doesn't that feature only work for generated class methods and not functions? I mean, you usually don't really have more than one file with the functions?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm sorry, these are class methods. I should have been more specific. I'll edit the question to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the rules **before the `method - by modifiers` (default) one**.

This way, your methods will always come first and then PHPStorm will order the rest like it usually does. If they're at the end, all of the methods will already have been consumed by the default rule, so the remaining rules won't matter.

Also, you need to specify `method` as you did in your second example.

Then, using `Rearrange Code` should do it (I've just tested it).

Comment: This worked great! Still looking for a way to enforce 2 newlines between these functions. The most I've been able to do is set 2 newlines between all class methods under the Code Style > PHP > Blank Lines tab, which isn't really what we wanted but should work.